Unpinned rows disappear when using api to update rows
I'm working with Datagrid for the first time and running into an issue with pinned rows disappearing completely when they are unpinned.I have a large, rapidly updating dataset, so am using the gridApiRef to update rows individually for performance reasons. However, it appears that when using this method rows that are pinned and unpinned disappear, despite still being listed in the rows property of the table.
Here's a codesandbox based off one of the MUI examples: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/datagrid-row-pin-bug-kjr2jq
To reproduce, add a few rows to the table, then pin and unpin a row. The row will disappear instead of being re-added to the table as a non-pinned row.
This seems to be logged as an issue already, but I'm hoping to find a workaround as the issue hasn't been touched in awhile.
